# Create a tempfile without opening it in Ruby

Tags: ruby, temporary-files

Is there a way to create a tempfile, without having it opened? I have to run an executable, redirect it's output to a file, and then read & parse that. Everything created by `tempfile` is already opened, and this triggers an error , because the file is locked.

Comment: I guess the executable is a separate process which maintains the tempfile opened (locked) while the ruby program is running. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, Sony Santos. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is using [FileUtils.touch](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/FileUtils.html#M001802) acceptable solution? You can touch a file and delete it once you are done with whatever you want.

Comment: #touch isn't too widely acceptable solution because significant advantage of the Dir::Tmpname (and in fact, crucial in most of cases) is the ensured unique filename.

Answer (score 25):

You can also use Dir::Tmpname

```
Dir::Tmpname.create('your_application_prefix') { |path| puts path }
```

path will contain unique path

See https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/lib/tmpdir.rb#L116

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get an error:

```
Andrew-Grimms-MacBook-Pro:~ agrimm$ irb
>> require "tempfile"
=> true
>> tempfile = Tempfile.new("temporary_file.txt", "/tmp")
=> #<File:/tmp/temporary_file.txt20110622-648-pkynjw-0>
>> tempfile.close
=> nil
>> system("echo foo > #{tempfile.path}")
=> true
>> system("cat #{tempfile.path}")
foo
=> true
>> tempfile.path
=> "/tmp/temporary_file.txt20110622-648-pkynjw-0"
>> exit
Andrew-Grimms-MacBook-Pro:~ agrimm$ cat /tmp/temporary_file.txt20110622-648-pkynjw-0
foo
```

Then again, the temporary file doesn't seem awfully temporary.

Does the error happen with all programs, or just a specific program? Also, can you post the code that causes the problem, and what error backtrace you get?

Comment: Andrew, perhaps Windows treats this differently. The error I received was `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

Comment: I guess you don't get an error because in your case the process which writes the tempfile is already finished when you try to use the file again. The problem here is that the executable is a separate process which maintains the file opened when the ruby program try to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use pipes.

If the executable is started from your ruby program, consider using [IO.popen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000880).

If they're different processes, you can try [named pipes](http://www.pauldix.net/2009/07/using-named-pipes-in-ruby-for-interprocess-communication.html).

Answer (score 0):

The [@timfjord's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6439353/316700) works. But if you don't need a block try:

```
Dir::Tmpname.create(['prefix-', '.ext']) {}
# => "/tmp/prefix-20190827-1-87n9iu.ext"
```